# how to update the data in specific position in the recyclerview without notifying the whole item? (Ex. text, image etc)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I need the functionality to update the data in the item in the recycler view. right now, If we notify the whole item it shows some fluctuation and we want to avoid refreshing the whole item on the UI.

I am using the ListAdapter with diff utils.

Comment: you very should post your current adapter and diffutil code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve your goal.

1. self-managing items. Adapter doesn't know anything about content of the items, it only puts items into RecyclerView. Content is managed by the item itself, so your problem is already solved.
2. custom adapter. Adapter has intricate knowledge about every item and can update selected ones accordingly.
3. `AsyncListDiffer` You can add differ to your adapter and it will take care of not updating parts that need no update.

Without seeing your code, we can't tell which way would be the most appropriate for you, but I guess adding differ is the simplest on already working code.

Comment: Actually, I have to pass some data in the adapter from the fragment(ex count etc) but the problem is that we have may view in the recycler view and can't access the views directly in the recycler view. So I need tho optimized logic to update the content in the recycler view without refreshing the whole item.

Comment: AsyncListDiffer will also refresh the whole item

Comment: Is it a good practice to use live observers in the recycler view?

Comment: @AnasMirza well, I don't know how your project is set up. I can only show you my sample, which is MVVM+databinding. It does refresh every single view in the RV item independently, but it might be not applicable if you have code in Fragments. https://github.com/szymonkubisiak/demo-android

Comment: exactly following the same architecture. the problem is that I am getting some data every second from the server and want to update it accordingly in the recycler view. and the data I am getting in ViewModel. we can do by using AsyncDiffUtil. But I am just looking more efficient way to perform this task instead of notifying the whole item.

Comment: can we use the LiveData for each item of the recycler view? so when the data is updated it will notify us automatically. Let me know If this is a good approach. Thanks for your help :) @Agent_L

Comment: @AnasMirza yeah, I think you can use LiveData. When an item is off-screen, it doesn't exist at all, so there should be no listeners so no harm in excessive updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom Adapter:

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about updating specific list items, and you're not using a `DiffUtil` (which will handle it for you) then you need to call the appropriate `notify*` method on your `Adapter`.

They fall into two categories, *item change events* (where the item list stays the same, but the displayed data for one or more of those items changes) and *structural change* events (where the actual list of items changes in some way, e.g. insertion/removal, or reordering).

I'm assuming you just want to update the displayed data for an item, so you should use one of the [`notifyItemChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemChanged(int)) or [`notifyItemRangeChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemRangeChanged(int,int)) methods to inform the adapter that a certain item (or range of items) needs to update. If any of those items are currently being displayed in a `ViewHolder`, then `onBindViewHolder` will get called again for those items - which is where you set all your text, images etc depending on the item you're displaying. So you'll update them with the current data.

Both those methods have a version that takes a payload `Object`/`Any`, where you can pass in *some data* to be used in a partial bind - basically, `onBindViewHolder` can receive that data and be smarter about the update, which means you can avoid things like reloading images, etc. by passing in *some stuff* and checking for it during the binding process. [More info about that here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onBindViewHolder(VH,int,java.util.List%3Cjava.lang.Object%3E)) in the other version of `onBindViewHolder` you can implement, if you need to.